# How to stream a video online while it is being generated and a failed CGI approach

Tags: python, video-streaming, streaming, cgi, live-streaming

I have a program that can generate video in real time. Now I would like to stream this video online while it is being generated. Does anybody know an easy way to do it?

I am describing a CGI approach I tried but did not work, but please note that I am open to all options that would achieve my goal. I am just wondering if anybody knows why my approach doesn't work and how I should fix it

I set the content-type to mpeg for example, and print out a chunk of data in the mpeg file periodically. But the video only lasts for very short amount of time and stop streaming. My code is something like this (in Python).

```
print "Content-type: video/mpeg"
print
f = open("test2.mpg")
while (True):
    st = f.read(1024*1024)
    sys.stdout.write(st)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Though this would work fine. I really don't see why the output of these two programs are different. But obviously I can't use this approach since i can't wait until the entire file is generated before reading in.

```
print "Content-type: video/mpeg"
print
f = open("test2.mpg")
print f.read()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of file is `test2.mpg`?

If it's an `mpeg4` file your approach won't work because you will have headers at the start or end of the file.
If your file is an `mpeg2` transport stream, then this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably hitting end-of-file and so your loop is failing, either with EOFError or crashing somewhere. If the video is being generated in real time, unless test2.mpg is a FIFO pipe (created using mkfifo -- in which case you can only have one reader at a time) -- reading from the pipe may return no data, and your loop is likely to run much, much faster than your video data is being saved. So you need a strategy to handle EOF.

Also, you need to make sure to flush your output -- both after the sys.stdout.write() line in this program, and after the video stream in the other program. Since your loop has no end condition and no output, and you may never end up writing any data, it could be that after one iteration of the loop, something fails, and the webserver discards the buffered data.

Additionally, reading a constant size of 1MB at a time may cause latency issues. For better latency, it's good to use smaller sizes; however, for better quality and throughput, you can use larger sizes. However, the latency point is moot if the program generating the video, your cgi script, or the webserver aren't all flushing at regular intervals.

I'd also suggest looking into "select" or "poll"/epoll -- either of those methods will give you better control over reading, and might help you solve the end-of-file issue by sleeping until data is available. If you find yourself needing to sleep(0.5), you might be better off using select/poll correctly.